# Avoid to loose the raster's attributes with xarray.open_mfdataset

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I'm trying to use `xarray.open_mfdataset` to read a raster and its attributes. When I use `rioxarray.open_rasterio` I'm be able to read the attributes saved as metadata into the rester.

```
data = rioxarray.open_rasterio(
      filename=file,
)
```

The code above return this output:

```
<xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 643, x: 991)>
[637213 values with dtype=float32]
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int64 1
  * x            (x) float64 4.332e+05 4.332e+05 ... 4.628e+05 4.629e+05
  * y            (y) float64 4.529e+06 4.529e+06 4.529e+06 ... 4.51e+06 4.51e+06
    spatial_ref  int64 0
Attributes:
    AREA_OR_POINT:     Area
    epsg:              32633
    max:               0.54965013
    min:               -0.16595216
    platform:          landsat-8
    sensing_datetime:  2017-04-10 09:46:42.149119
    tile:              ROW_031_PATH_190
    scale_factor:      1.0
    add_offset:        0.0
```

The *Attributes* are useful for successives step like read the sensig datetime `data.attrs['sensing_datetime']`.

When I use `xarray.open_mfdataset` on the same file:

```
data = xr.open_mfdataset(
      paths=file,
      chunks={'x': 512, 'y': 512},
      parallel=True,
)
```

I see this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (band: 1, x: 991, y: 643)
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int64 1
  * x            (x) float64 4.332e+05 4.332e+05 ... 4.628e+05 4.629e+05
  * y            (y) float64 4.529e+06 4.529e+06 4.529e+06 ... 4.51e+06 4.51e+06
    spatial_ref  int64 ...
Data variables:
    band_data    (band, y, x) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 512, 512), meta=np.ndarray>
```

Is there a way to avoid to loose the attributes with `xarray.open_mfdataset`?

Comment: Why would you use open_mfdataset for one file ? Does a simple open_dataset give the same result (no attrs) ?

Comment: Because I've seen that [is used for NetCDF, Zarr and others](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_dataset.html#xarray.open_dataset) but not for GeoTiff. Engine attribute says: '{"netcdf4", "scipy", "pydap", "h5netcdf", "pynio", "pseudonetcdf", "zarr", None}'

Comment: If data is your xarray.Dataset, isn't data['band_data'].attrs the dictionnary you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you @cyril ! `data['band_data'].attrs` runs both with `xarray.open_mfdataset` and `xarray.open_dataset`. If you answer my question I vote you :)

Comment: `xarray.open_dataset` can read GeoTiff even if in the documentation isn't mentioned `rasterio` as possible engine. I've tested now. So, I need to correct my previous comment.